# Mocking a class name with an enum

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, enums

Currently, in the code we have roles as models (and tables in the database).

I wanted to make a user_role class with enums without having to create a sub-model, but I would like to transition the current roles into this class with minimal changes to the codebase.

Currently, the existing roles use class methods by the role name and not `UserRole`.

example:

```
class UserRole < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :user

  # when adding a new role add a has_one association to the user model
  enum role: {
    view_only: 0,
    director: 1,
    admin: 2
  }

  validates :role, uniqueness: { scope: :user_id }
end
```

And I would like to be able to use `Director.where`, `Director.all`, etc.

If this is a code smell, I will just stick to migrating the current code instead of introducing more sub-models with not much value.

Comment: Single table inheritance might help you here. If `UserRole` only has the role column, it seems like an overkill having to fetch an extra table. Ignore if already using that.

Comment: I wouldn't exactly say that its a code smell or an antipattern, but when devising a authorization system you should put a bit more thought into your current and anticipated requirements. Are roles always going to be "global" or will you be needing to scope them to resources? Are you conflating the idea of roles (director, admin) with actual access control directives (view_only)? Does a User with the director role really need to behave differently in your application (you probally don't need STI)?

Comment: How many roles do you anticipate having and how much do you expect them to change? In general using a enum here is the easy naive solution but it doesn't handle complexity very well. I would take a look at the Rolify gem if you want to see a very flexible and tested solution. Also if you're using Pundit you most likely won't actually want or need to have separate models.

Comment: I have 2 existing roles that I would either need to change code, or make them a class somehow. I expect roles to grow. A user can have many roles with different access to different accounts in the app. There are some global roles that are not affiliated with accounts, and override all app usage, so I don't use the join table or that. I know I'm not super clear, working with legacy code and can't spend the time rewriting the whole app, but def don't want to make it worse than it is!

Comment: My experience is that whenever someone starts creating multiple "user" classes it's a clusterf*ck. It just ends up mushing the two separate concerns of user identity and authorization together in a very bad way. So yeah, there is a definate risk of making it worse.

Comment: @max How would you give authorization for a user to resources, that can be assigned within the app. This account you can view, this account you can create, and this account you can create and edit (and more and more, this is oversimplifying). A user has many accounts and different access to these accounts.

Comment: It's a rabbit hole, @madav, but check out Zanzibar and SpiceDb. Google wrote the Zanzibar paper when developing the authorization system for their apps like GMail and Google Drive. It's granular permissions management for varied resources. For a much simpler implementation, check out Cancan or Pundit.